# How to get PublicIp in the json file

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to configure pixelstreaming on AWS, most of the things are working now except one hitch, there is a config.json file (given below). the part where it says PublicIP i have to add the ip of the instance manually, is it possible to make it so it gets the IP itself since i want to spawn 50 instances and do not want to go to each instance and edit the IP.

```
{
    "UseFrontend": false,
    "UseMatchmaker": true,
    "UseHTTPS": false,
    "UseAuthentication": false,
    "LogToFile": true,
    "HomepageFile": "/public/player.html",
    "AdditionalRoutes": {},
    "EnableWebserver": true,
    "MatchmakerAddress": "",
    "MatchmakerPort": "9999",
    "PublicIp": "localhost",
    "HttpPort": 80,
    "HttpsPort": 443,
    "StreamerPort": 8888
}
```

Comment: this question in not about the `javascript` or `json` please use the proper tags.

Answer (score 0):

If you can execute a bash script on host startup, you could do this:

For linux systems:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
IP=$(curl -s https://checkip.amazonaws.com)
sed -i "s/localhost/$IP/g" /path/to/config.json
```

For windows systems:

```powershell
powershell -Command "& {$filePath = 'C:\Path\to\your\config.json'; $response = (Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Uri 'https://checkip.amazonaws.com').Content; $body = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString($response); $clean = $body.Trim(); (Get-Content $filePath) -replace 'localhost', $clean | Out-File -encoding UTF8 $filePath; }"
```

Source for IP check url is here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-services-ec2-sg.html#configuring-a-security-group

Comment: Thanks a lot Rob, will surely try this.

Comment: Alright I forgot to add its a Window instance. sorry about that.

Comment: I've added a powershell equivalent that should work on modern windows systems